# linear-algebra- basis of $M_{22}$ subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

$S$ is a two rows and two column matrix where $a_{11} =a, a_{12} = b, a_{21} = c,  a_{22} = d$ which is an element of $M_{22}$

I am given $a=b$ and $b+2c=0$

How do I prove that $S$ is a subspace of $M_{22}$, when there is no value of $d$?

Comment: To prove that a subset is a subspace you need to check some things, namely that it is closed under scalar multiplication and addition. Is this the case?

Comment: this is all the information i have, I am confused on how to prove this without value of d

Comment: The point is that $d$ is free to change, you don't have to check anything about it. The only thing you need, as shown below, is to check that the sum still respects the conditions on the entries you are given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} -2c & -2c\\ c & d \end{pmatrix}:c,d \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$. We have:

$\begin{pmatrix} -2x & -2x \\ x & y \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} -2u & -2u \\ u & v \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -2(x+u) & -2(x+u) \\ x+u & y+ v \end{pmatrix} \in S$,

and
$r\begin{pmatrix} -2x & -2x \\ x & y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -2rx & -2rx \\ rx & ry \end{pmatrix} \in S$.

Thus $S$ is a subspace of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: If I were to take a basis from this S, how would I take it?

Comment: $\mathcal{B} = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} -2 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$

Comment: How did you get the second matrix ( I undestand how you got the second one now), and is the dimension of S=3?

Comment: it comes from splitting "$c$ "and "$d$". $\text{dim}S = 2$.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot a=b was represented in c